# Spring beans initialization through method

Tags: java, spring, configuration, spring-bean

I have a little question about bean creation that bothers me a lot.

For example I have classes

```
public class A {
    B b;
    public A(B b) { 
        this.b = b;
    }
}
public class B {}
```

And I want to make beans for them like this:

```
@Configuration 
public class Config {

@Bean
public B beanB() {
    return new B();
}
//version 1
@Bean
public A beanA() {
    return new A(beanB())
}
//version 2
@Bean
public A beanA(B beanB) {
    return new A(beanB)
}
}
```

So, my question is what is the right way to create bean A?

I think that the right one is version 2, because in the version 1 I think beanB can be invoked 2 times: on the creation of beanA and when spring will create it for it's context. But I can't find anything that will prove my opinion.

Comment: it doesn't matter how many times you invoke `beanB()`  from spring managed beans spring will guaranty that only one instance of  it is present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "right" way is to do it the way the **documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`@Bean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html), shows it:

> ***`@Bean` Methods in `@Configuration` Classes***
>
> Typically, `@Bean` methods are declared within `@Configuration` classes. In this case, bean methods may reference other `@Bean` methods in the same class by calling them *directly*. This ensures that references between beans are strongly typed and navigable. Such so-called *'inter-bean references'* are guaranteed to respect scoping and AOP semantics, just like `getBean()` lookups would. These are the semantics known from the original 'Spring JavaConfig' project which require CGLIB subclassing of each such configuration class at runtime. As a consequence, `@Configuration` classes and their factory methods must not be marked as final or private in this mode. For example:
>
> ```java
> @Configuration
> public class AppConfig {
>
>  @Bean
>  public FooService fooService() {
>      return new FooService(fooRepository());
>  }
>
>  @Bean
>  public FooRepository fooRepository() {
>      return new JdbcFooRepository(dataSource());
>  }
>
>  // ...
> }
> ```

That means version 1 in the question code.

Spring dynamically subclasses `AppConfig`, so only one instance is created no matter how many times the method is called, e.g. functionally something like this:

```java
public class $dynamic$ extends AppConfig {
    private FooRepository cachedFooRepository;

    @Override
    public FooRepository fooRepository() {
        if (this.cachedFooRepository == null)
            this.cachedFooRepository = super.fooRepository();
        return cachedFooRepository;
    }
}
```